# Pandas group by and count by date. Then transpose the count to column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {"_id": "1", "date": datetime.strptime("2020-09-29 07:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "status": "started"},
    {"_id": "2", "date": datetime.strptime("2020-09-29 14:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "status": "end"},
    {"_id": "3", "date": datetime.strptime("2020-09-25 17:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "status": "started"},
    {"_id": "4", "date": datetime.strptime("2020-09-17 09:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "status": "end"},
    {"_id": "5", "date": datetime.strptime("2020-09-19 07:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "status": "end"},
    {"_id": "6", "date": datetime.strptime("2020-09-19 08:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "status": "end"},
]).set_index('date')
```

Which looks like this:

```
                    _id   status
date                            
2020-09-29 07:00:00   1  started
2020-09-29 14:00:00   2      end
2020-09-25 17:00:00   3  started
2020-09-17 09:00:00   4      end
2020-09-19 07:00:00   5      end
```

---

I'm trying to group by days and to count each status. But I would like to have the name of the name in the column name.

Here is the desired output:

```
                      status_started  status_end
date
2020-09-29 07:00:00    1                1
2020-09-25 17:00:00    1                0
2020-09-17 09:00:00    0                1
2020-09-19 07:00:00    0                2
```

---

I've tried this:

```
df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='d'), 'status']).agg({'status': "count"})
df = df.reset_index(level="status")

out: 
                    status
date       status         
2020-09-17 end           1
2020-09-19 end           2
2020-09-25 started       1
2020-09-29 end           1
2020-09-29 started       1
```

but did not successfully transform the df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `crosstab`:

```
d = pd.crosstab(df.index.date, df['status'])\
      .rename_axis('date').add_prefix('status_')
```

---

```
status      status_end  status_started
date                                  
2020-09-17           1               0
2020-09-19           2               0
2020-09-25           0               1
2020-09-29           1               1
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need `unstack`:

```
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='d'), 'status']).size().unstack('status', fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
status      end  started
date                    
2020-09-17    1        0
2020-09-19    2        0
2020-09-25    0        1
2020-09-29    1        1
```